# Azure Service Configuration Files

Tags: azure, configuration, azure-web-roles

So I have been banging my head against a wall on this one...I am trying to publish an Azure Web Role and I have two ServiceConfiguration files:

- ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg
- ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg

In my publish xml I have:

```
<AzureServiceConfiguration>Cloud</AzureServiceConfiguration>
```

So my assumption here is that when I publish it will use the Cloud cfg.

For working locally, under the emulator I have set the flag for local debugging to use Local.

[image]

However it would seem that this flag here also determines the cscfg to use for the cloud...so I am a little confused - is this the correct behavior or am I missing something? I really want to have a separate one for local as I have different values I need.

**Update**

Suddenly it started to work fine today. Didn't really change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tom, your publish XML configuration file is OK, and your publish to Azure will use the .Cloud.cscfg.

You can pick which of the configuration files you want to use when publishing (right click > Publish...), on the second screen (under Service configuration).

What you did for your local environment should work fine, and use the .Local.cscfg file.

Comment: So this is what I tried but despite choosing Cloud on the publish screen it still uses the local. If I switch it on the run/debug setting it seems to work. I am using VS 2013.

Comment: So it seemed to have started working now...not quite sure why.